# Powershell Results when exporting to HTML

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon everyone. I have something I am trying to figure out how to fix.

When I pull up Powershell commands, such as `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select -Exp LastBootUpTime`, it gives me the correct output for date & time in long format.

However, when I export the powershell script I have to a nice HTML report, I get the following:

`System Creation Time  03/01/2018 14:56:45
Last System Boot Time   01/25/2021 23:11:05`

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait, so what exactly is the issue? That its getting the creation time, and boot time?

Comment: On the console you see the standard format of a `[DateTime]` object. When you export it to html another method for the formatting is used. You could use a calculated property to make sure you get the format you want.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - No, the issue is I was trying to figure out how to have the HTML Results populate in the long format like the command prompt does.

Comment: @Olaf - Yeah, all the calculating isn't worth it. LOL I was hoping there was a simple way to export it in Long Date/Time Format.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - is there some reason not to use `.ToString()` with one of the standard format codes? this >>> Standard date and time format strings | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: See, install and use the HTML module(s) from the Microsoft powershellgallery.com.  `Find-Module -Name '*html*'`, specifically the `PSWriteHTML` and `ReportHTML` ones.

Answer (score 0):

As the `Get-CimInstance` command outputs a `DateTime` object by default it's actually quite easy to force it to export it the way you want. In your case this should be enough.

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastBootUpTime).ToLongDateString()
```

Comment: Or if you are looking to include other properties along with LastBootUpTime you could make it a custom property like so `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption, CSName, @{n='LastBootUpTime';e={$_.LastBootUpTime.ToLongDateString()} }`